# how to order array evenly by property

Tags: ruby

I have the following array:

```
arr = [
   { name: 'Apple', store: 'A' },
   { name: 'Banana', store: 'A' },
   { name: 'Carrot', store: 'B' },
   { name: 'Potato', store: 'B' },
   { name: 'Tomato', store: 'A' }
]
```

I need to sort the array by switching between each store like this:

```
arr = [
   { name: 'Apple', store: 'A' },
   { name: 'Carrot', store: 'B' },
   { name: 'Banana', store: 'A' },
   { name: 'Tomato', store: 'B' },
   { name: 'Potato', store: 'A' }

]
```

How can I do that with ruby ?

Comment: Why is the Carrot second? You could accomplish, something, with `sort` but it's unclear what's the  sorting criteria.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Neither the fruits are sorted nor the store alters properly. Can you please elaborate on the sorting rules?

Comment: I need to sort, alternating by store

Comment: Are you sure that in the second "sorted" array you should have Tomato/B and Potato/A and not Tomato/A and Potato/B as in the first array? Isn't it a typo?

Comment: yes, forget name property, just need the sort alternating by store A and B

Answer (score 2):

I came up with something :)

```
arr = [
 { name: 'Apple', store: 'A' },
 { name: 'Banana', store: 'A' },
 { name: 'Carrot', store: 'B' },
 { name: 'Potato', store: 'B' },
 { name: 'Tomato', store: 'A' }
]

first, *rest = arr.group_by { |h| h[:store] }.values

first.zip(*rest).flatten.compact
```

See it in action: [Replit](https://replit.com/@razvan-sv/LoathsomeCyberCoordinate#main.rb)

Comment: Don't we need the sorting step after `group_by...values` to ensure each "partition" is sorted (by name, I assume)?

Comment: There is no requirement to sort the `name` , but could be added.

Comment: Nice use of `zip`!

Comment: @jujajjjj Is the answer ok?